# How can I set the return value of a MagicMock object to be equal to some value when asserting in a unit test?

Tags: python, mocking

I have a function that calls on an API endpoint:

```
class CAPIyDownload:

    def __init__(self, finfo: FileSpec):
        self.finfo = finfo

    def authenticate(self):
        """Authenticates user credentials and returns a token"""

        headers = {"Host": self.nfo.extra['autt'],
                   "Content-Type": "www.rm-urlencoded", }

        res = {
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        }


        # send post request to generate access_token, then return it
        response = requests.post(self.finfo.extra['auth_url'], data=res, headers=headers)
        token = response.json()['access_token']
        return token
```

I am trying to mock out the above `request` and `response` and simply test that `token` is some string value. Here is how I do it:

```
class TestAlbum(unittest.TestCase):
@mock.patch("exchanges.parse_control.FileSpec")
@mock.patch("exchanges.parse_control.requests")
def test_cme_authenticate(self, mock_requests, mock_filespec):
    finfo = MagicMock(spec=FileSpec)
    finfo.port = 12345
    ...

    mock_response = MagicMock()
    mock_response.status_code = 200
    mock_response.json.return_value = {'access_token':'123'}
    mock_requests.get.return_value = mock_response
    cme_ref_api = CAPIyDownload(finfo)
    self.assertEqual(cme_ref_api.authenticate(), '123')
```

When I run the test, I get:

```
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='requests.post().json().__getitem__()' id='140314359423712'> != '123'
```

Comment: You are setting the return value of `mock_requests.get`, not `mock_requests.post`.